# Visual Studio Code settings ignore project files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've noticed that in my project, my project files don't adhere to the settings. EG tab == 4 spaces. Tabs are only adding 2 spaces. The settings file does it properly. It uses 4 spaces with I hit tab. Do I need to add something to include the project files? I've tried adding this to my user settings. I also added this to the workspace settings but it still didn't seem to work.

```
"editor.insertSpaces": false,
"editor.tabSize": 4,
```

and tried using true as well. It just doesn't do it. The project files seem to be ignored. Is there some place I can fix this?

Comment: Are those settings set differently in your own settings file and you're looking at the defaults instead? https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userandworkspace

Comment: @AdamMartin No, those are setting in my user settings file (the global one. I don't have a workspace settings file yet as my understanding is that is specific to the project. The User Settings are supposed to apply to everything (I thought). But I tried a workspace settings file too and it still didn't seem to help.

Comment: Do you have `"editor.detectIndentation": false,`?

Comment: ah, thanks! That was it. Soo many settings lol. I just overlooked it.
@AdamMartin Mind making that an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also set `"editor.detectIndentation": false,`, otherwise the program auto-detects the indentation based on the open file.  [Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userandworkspace) has default file that should help with any other settings.